# Gnome shell takes a lot of memory

Tags: gnome, ram, memory-usage

Is it normal that after fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gnome shell takes 255 MB of RAM?
If not, What should i do to solve that problem?

Comment: it's a bug: see here https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297 and they seem to be working on it.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen two instances (using `htop`): one of my user 320MB, other of 'gdm' user 200MB, of resident memory, so a total of more than 500MB, and I just started the computer (not much usage I mean), version: 'GNOME Shell 3.28.4' :/